# Generation of IPA using Command line tools

Tags: xcode, terminal, command, line, ipa

I am generating the IPA file using command line tools for custom IPA generation. Each time, it asks for login credentials during code signing. However, this doesn't work for me because I always use a different developer's profile to generate the IPA. Consequently, I am unable to enter the login passcode for each developer's profile. Please let me know if there are any other steps to avoid code signing while generating the IPA file.
The scripts as follows: xcodebuild -workspace -scheme -archivePath archive xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath -exportPath -exportOptionsPlist.

I am working on automating the IPA generartion Process using Command line tools in Mac by calling the above Script.

Please help us in solving my issue.